# Post-hoc with Bonferroni a correction after ANOVA with repeated measure in SPSS

Tags: spss, post-hoc, bonferroni

does somebody know where I can find the t value of post-hoc tests with Bonferroni correction when using SPSS.From what I get so far, I only see p values. Should I add a command in the script? Thank you

Comment: Only the p-values are corrected with the Bonferroni procedure, the t-values are unchanged.

Comment: I'm voting to close at the moment, since this seems to just be asking about particular options in SPSS. It would help if you could be more explicit about the type of tests you are conducting (e.g. one way ANOVA, generalized linear models?, etc.) Bonferroni is pretty easy to calculate yourself by hand.